# Рисование дуги в зависимости от входных данных времени [PHP]

Tags: gd, php, css, javascript

Всем привет!
Мне нужно нарисовать участок окружности, в зависимости от входных данных времени. Например, с **6:00 до 9:00**, участок окружности будет таким:

[image]

Синий участок мне и нужно прорисовывать. Соответственно с 00:10 до 03:20 график участок окружности будет в другом месте. Надеюсь, что все понятно-ясно.

Думал использовать **GD** библиотеку, но, не знаю как ( Возможно тут вопрос с геометрией и с **sin** и **cos**.
Спасибо.

**P.S.** Я не знаю, может есть способ это сделать через **JavaScript** и/или **CSS**.

Comment: Пардон, я, может быть, чего-то не понимаю но с помощью php вы на чем собрались всё это рисовать?  Прям на сервере?

Comment: Есть же такая библиотека: GD, при помощи которой можно рисовать различные геометрические фигуры и прочее.

Comment: @DreamChild, [почему бы и нет][1]?

@frops, всё же не советовал бы делать это на сервере. Почитайте про [canvas][2], на нём ваша задача достаточно просто решается с помощью метода `arc`.


  1: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php
  2: http://habrahabr.ru/post/111308/

Comment: Точно,Canvas. Надо будет попробовать! Но, это только HTML5 (

Answer (score 3):

Небольшой пример на СSS3, изображения пока прикреплять не могу :(

```
<style>
.half-circle{
 border: solid 4px orange;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
</style>
```

Статья в тему на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/).